# Upgrade fails at unpacking perl

Tags: raspbian, update

I am trying to upgrade Raspbian Jessie 2016-02-26. Every time I try, the Pi hangs at

> unpacking perl (5.20.2-3+deb8u4)  over  (5.20.2-3+deb8u3)

I have a 32 GB SD Card and have expanded the partition. Several re-attempts fail at the same place, each time. The Pi hangs with no response to the mouse or anything. Even the clock has frozen.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue at last.
The SD card was the problem !
The SD card I used was a Maplin branded 32GB card which I then replaced with a Sandisk 16GB card and the problem went away.
Until this incident I was ignorant of the speed class rating of SD cards. Both of the cards I have used were rated class 4.
I think the Maplin card was just not up to the Job although it works fine on a video camera. I have since purchased a Sandisk 16GB card with a rated speed of class 10 and have found that using this has given me a dramatic improvement in the speed of the Pi.

Comment: Oddly enough, I had a couple of expensive Kingston cards fail at the perl installation stage too with this same Raspbian version.

Comment: Hmmm.  The package manager itself may depend on perl, so if things were getting generally/frequently screwed up it may just not be noticeable until that point.